# How to check which ajax call request is

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, geocoding

I am getting address detail from google geocoder api passing latitude and langitude for that I am calling  ajax request .I am getting data succesfully but my problem is **how do I know that which ajax call respose is because I have 100 of ajax request**

I have tried following ways:

```
  var requestdata = [];
  $.each(lat_lang_arr, function (index, value) {
      var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + value.lat + "," + value.lang + ";
      var request = $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: 'GET',
          success: function (resp) {
              console.log(resp);
          }
      })

  });
  requestdata.push(request);
```

**I also tried this:**

```
$.when.apply(null, requestdata)
    .done(function () {

    })
```

Can somebody help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: just write it in your ajaxSuccess?

Comment: @Mazz but i have parallel ajax rquest

Comment: What do you wanna do with the data?

Comment: getting address information by passing lat and lang

Answer (score 0):

Hello on way to do that is to add inc variable and push the result request in your table

```
requestdata[i] = resp
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the current ajax call request url in success, thus we will know which url request it is,

```js
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + value.lat + "," + value.lang + ";
      var request = $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: 'GET',
          success: function (resp) {
              var urlCode=this.url.split("?latlng=");
//u will get the latlng value
          }
      })
```